# Why isn't this default_scope working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope, default-scope

I'm trying to set a default scope so that Users where `notified: true` are soft-deleted. `notified` is a boolean data column.

This is what I've tried:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where('notified != ?', true) }
  #...
end
```

But this way, no users appear in any scope. ie - all the users appear to be soft-deleted, even the ones with `notified: false` or `notified: nil`. What's wrong with my scope?

Comment: Can you show us the code hat is doing the deleting too?

Comment: @TarynEast Well the users aren't actually being deleted. Setting a default_scope "soft deletes" them, so they are no longer included in database queries, but they're still in the database. I don't believe there is any other relevant code.

Comment: Yes.. the line of code that actually deletes the users. Are you using `User.delete_all` or what?

Comment: Sorry you said int he question they are all being deleted, and in your comment you say none of them are deleted... which is which?

Comment: oh wait - you don't mean they're deleted.. you mean "the users aren't showing up when i try to get users"... that's a very different thing.

Comment: @TarynEast It's called "soft-deletion" when the records are technically still in the database but they won't be returned by any queries.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'm aware of what soft-deletion is - the wording for me was not clear as to what you were trying to do. how about I edit your question to something that would have made it clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using boolean values the database understands. In this case you want to see users that have a notified that is not true, so I'd user:

```
default_scope { where('notified IS NOT TRUE') }
```

That way users will only appear in other scopes if their boolean database values is `FALSE` or `NULL`.

Note: default scopes are actually considered a code smell... because they're a bit magic and hide away what you really mean when you fetch out users. You might want to instead create an `active` and `inactive` scope and specify them explicitly in your code eg:

```
scope :active ->{ where('notified IS NOT TRUE') }
scope :inactive ->{ where('notified IS TRUE') }

# in your controller
def index
  @users = User.active.all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your objective of 'set a default scope so that Users where notified != true are soft-deleted.', you should use `default_scope { where(manual_down: true) }`, which will only retrieve the records with that column is TRUE, and ignore the others (FALSE or NIL)

I totally agree with Taryn East. Changing/removing default_scope might require lots of modification to logic that depends on that model, so use it only if you're sure you don't change the default_scope condition later (which is usually not the case).

Comment: Oh, that was a mistake on my part. I meant to say that I want to soft-delete the Users where `notified: true`. How can I ignore records where the column is TRUE?

Comment: Hmm, your scope should work as you're describing. You sure it's a boolean data type and not a String data type? Can you paste the result of `User.unscoped.where("notified is not null").map(&:notified).uniq`

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a boolean. `User.unscoped.where("notified is not null")` just prints out a list of all the relevant records.

Comment: Actually I just figured out that `User.where('notified != ?', true)` includes Users where notifed=false, but not where notified is nil.

Comment: If so, I recommend @Taryn East solution, `default_scope { where("notified IS NOT TRUE") }` seems to work with your case